# Is it possible uninstalling of a program installed with `make` or `gmake`?

Tags: makefile, installation, uninstallation, gnu-make

Is it possible uninstalling of a program installed with `make` or `gmake`? If possible, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually there should be a target `make uninstall` when install from source. which should be executed in the same place where you executed make (in the source). if you want to make sure you will be able to uninstall a software prior to installing it you should use checkinstall to verify that there is indeed an uninstall target.

Comment: I've never seen an uninstall target.  I think it's pretty rare.

Comment: well it should exist in every well developed project i guess.. sometimes it may be called remove or something like this ...

Comment: the checkinstall is an utility which you should use it after you have done your configure in the source of the project that you want to install. after this u use checkinstall to make the source. this utility will keep track of all the files that this project edited in the filesystem. with this later you can use checkinstall to uninstall the software. so all in all you do ./configure make. after this instead of using make install you do checkinstall.. you answer few questions and your package is installed and an uninstall target is added.page is http://www.asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall